# What means a polyhedron doesn't contain a line?

Tags: geometry

[Please click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyQLv.png)

This image is from the book "Bertsimas Introduction to Linear Optimization 1997". I can't get the intuitive behind the meaning of the image. I mean how polyhedron Q doesn't contain a line? We can draw a line inside Q between any two points in the shaded area, so how come Q doesn't contain a line?
Yet I understand that P doesn't contain extreme points. My main struggle with the meaning of "contains a line".

Comment: A line means a whole line, going off to infinity in both directions.

Comment: Oh this explains everything. So not line with finite length, it should be with infinite length. Right?

Comment: @MoFarouk Right.

Comment: @MoFarouk No, infinite length would already happen in one direction. You better correctly distinguish betwen *lines* (infinite in both direcrtions) *rays* (infinite in one of the two directions), and *line segments* (of finite length).